# Syntax error in Postgres using if statement

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Using the DBeaver tool to run PostgreSQL, and getting error SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "if"

query -

```
DO $$
if (1<2) then select 1
end if;
end $$;
```

Comment: It's not valid plpgsql and you didn't mention another language

Comment: A `do` block can't return a result to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html
=>> `42601  syntax_error` means syntax error.

Google search "postgresql do block" will link you to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html
By imitate manual example. You can rewrite the following way.

```
DO $$
begin
if (1<2) then raise info '1';
end if;
end $$;
```